# How to add Log4j to Eclipse RCP project

Tags: log4j, eclipse-rcp

I made a plug-in project from this [article](http://mahichir.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/put-log4j-within-slf4j-in-your-eclipse-rcp-application/#comments).
Then I add this plug-in into my project. However, when I try to use it,

I got the following error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/sel4j/log4j/api/LoggerFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.sel4j.log4j.api.LoggerFactory`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the same setup as on this screenshot?:
[image]

Note, that you need to add your jars to the classpath as shown on the screenshot and not as you would usually do it for your Java application: Right Click-> Add to build path.

Also, I would like to suggest using [this article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/franey-logging/?source=archives) for setting up logging with Eclipse-RCP for the first time. It is more complete and precise.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the wrong jar files. Now it works.